# asp:timer object renders as <span>

Tags: 2010, ajax

I'm creating a custom web part in 2010 that I'm attempting to render asynchronously. To do this, most everything is wrapped inside of an UpdatePanel that we've set the UpdateMode to "Conditional". I've defined that the trigger for this the "Tick" event of an asp Timer object.

For some annoying reason, IE8 (which my client requires to be supported) constantly creates HTTP requests to my page. We've been disabling the timer on the server-side, so I thought I'd try it from the client side. However, after looking at the HTML code that gets rendered, SharePoint is rendering my ASP:Timer objects as spans, which causes me to lose all of the functionality.

Am I doing something incorrect or is there a way to stop SharePoint from rendering it this way?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have solved my problem.

$('span[id*="tmrDelayedFeedRender"]')[0].control._stopTimer();

Where 'tmrDelayedFeedRender' is the ID of my ASP timer control.